# Web.xml: Are url-pattern tags relative to each other?

Tags: xml, tomcat, jboss, web.xml, security-constraint

```
   <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>myName</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/aName</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>

    <security-constraint>

            <web-resource-collection>

                    ...

                    <url-pattern>
                            /*
                    </url-pattern>

            </web-resource-collection>

             ...

    </security-constraint>
```

This is an excerpt from web.xml (using it to configure a jboss/tomcat webservice).  Just wondering if the `url-pattern` in `web-resource-collection` is relative to the `url-pattern` in `servlet-mapping`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `url-pattern` used to select the constraints for a given request are not relative to anything. The interesting parts of the Servlet spec here are:

> #### SRV.12.8.3       Processing Requests
>
> *When a Servlet container receives a
>   request, it shall use the algorithm
>   described in SRV.11.1 to select the
>   constraints (if any) defined on the
>   `url-pattern` that is the best match to
>   the request URI.* If no constraints are
>   selected, the container shall accept
>   the request. Otherwise the container
>   shall determine if the HTTP method of
>   the request is constrained at the
>   selected pattern. If it is not, the
>   request shall be accepted. Otherwise,
>   the request must satisfy the
>   constraints that apply to the `http-method`
>   at the `url-pattern`. Both of the
>   following rules must be satisfied for
>   the request to be accepted and
>   dispatched to the associated servlet.

And:

> #### SRV.11.1          Use of URL Paths
>
> Upon receipt of a client request, the Web container determines the Web application
>   to which to forward it. The Web application selected must have the longest
>   context path that matches the start of the request URL. The matched part of the URL
>   is the context path when mapping to servlets.
>
> *The Web container next must locate the servlet to process the request using
>   the path mapping procedure described below*.
>
> The path used for mapping to a servlet is the request URL from the request
>   object minus the context path and the path parameters. The URL path mapping
>   rules below are used in order. The first successful match is used with no further
>   matches attempted:
>
> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the
>      path of the servlet. A successful match selects the servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done
>      by stepping down the path tree a directory at a time, using the ’/’ character as
>      a path separator. The longest match determines the servlet selected.
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet container will try to match a servlet that handles requests for the extension.
>      An extension is defined as the part of the last segment after the last ’.’ char-
>      acter.
> 4. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will
>      attempt to serve content appropriate for the resource requested. If a "default"
>      servlet is defined for the application, it will be used.
>
> #### SRV.11.2          Specification of Mappings
>
> In the Web application deployment descriptor, the following syntax is used to define
>   mappings:
>
> - A string beginning with a ‘/’ character and ending with a ‘/*’ suffix is used
>      for path mapping.
> - A string beginning with a ‘*.’ prefix is used as an extension mapping.
> - A string containing only the ’/’ character indicates the "default" servlet of
>      the application. In this case the servlet path is the request URI minus the context path and the path info is null.
> - All other strings are used for exact matches only.

Answer (score 5):

It would make sense to me that the *security-constraint/web-resource-collection/url-pattern* is **not** relative to the *servlet-mapping/url-pattern*, for the following reason: there can be several *servlet-mapping* elements in web.xml, in which case it would not be clear which *servlet-mapping/url-pattern* to take to resolve the relative URI, were it one.
(Just a guess - I have not used security constraints in tomcat yet).

Answer (score 1):

No, they are not relative to each other; there is no way to bind a given *servlet-mapping* to a *security-constraint*. Both are applied to a given URL pattern, security constraint can also be applied only to specific HTTP methods (GET, POST, ...) so they are quite independent.

Both elements are defined and described in the [Servlet specification](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/download.html). You might want to read sections SRV.12.8 about security, and details about the url-pattern element.